# ViewModel or ValueConverter for WPF View

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application to display incoming bytes from a serial stream. I want to display these bytes inside a user control that allows for changes (i.e. byte value changes meaning background color changes to alert user, user chooses to view data as hex/decimal/binary). So far, I have an

```
ObservableCollection<ByteDisplay>
```

where `ByteDisplay` is a WPF User Control bound to a data model with a few relevant properties: **DisplayFormat** (enum Hex/Binary/Decimal), **Data** (the actual byte value), and **BgColor** (a string representing a system color to denote that a value has changed).

My problem is that I have to completely replace the DataContext of the `ByteDisplay` to get changes to show in the aggregate view that holds this collection. I think I could get around this with a ValueConverter for the collection of raw bytes, instead of completing the change in the Aggregate View's ViewModel, but is this the right approach?

Comment: Don't create observable collections of UI element, you should have a strict separation of data and view components.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use an ObservableCollection? Sounds really strange though.

In my opinion, you can simply create a user control bound to a view model by following the MVVM pattern.

Here you can have textblocks, textboxes, datagrids, charts, etc which binds to properties in the view model. You could also bind the background property to viewmodel or use a converter as you said. Like if you have some other property referring to that, say you're displaying some value in a textbox and you use the same value for changing the background color to warn the user, then use a converter.

It's as simple as this. I did not understand the logic behind creating an ObservableCollection still.

Comment: ObservableCollection allows byte array to grow and shrink with corresponding view changes, without me needing to manage that.

Comment: But are you sure it doesn't have any impact on performance or memory management?

Comment: If there is an impact, it is negligible. My concern is letting the library do the work for me where possible.

Comment: Why don't you try an MVVM approach?

Comment: I guess this is really my misunderstanding. I thought this was an MVVM approach. Can you show me where I failed on this? I have the triad, but this particular view is really a collection of smaller views. Can you edit your answer with a code example, maybe?

Comment: Without seeing your entire code, I cant suggest a proper solution. Did you mean that you have a main view and many subviews under it? And these subviews are just used for changing the background and data? 
If you have the appearance in common, ie all views have the same design view, then it's better to go with MVVM. Read more about MVVM. You can have a single view and bind the view properties to view model properties and change the properties in VM according to reception of events, or some action.